# Why does 'this' behave differently in a lambda than in 'function ()' using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This tripped me up for a while. I had assumed they were the exact same thing. When using the `function ()` syntax with jQuery `.each()`, `this` would refer to the current element, as per the documentation. When I wrote it using lambda syntax `this` seemed to refer to the entire Window. To be safe I used the `(index, element)` callback to make sure I'm always working with the element, but I'm still unclear as to why it behaves differently depending on syntax. See example.

```js
function test() {
  $(".foo").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
  
  $(".bar").each(() => 
    console.log($(this).text())
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="bar">Bar</div>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Comment: That is just how arrow functions work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: This is not jQuery specific.